# Inflection points of a real planar singular cubic curve

Tags: algebraic-curves

Consider a real planar singular cubic curve.  After an affine change of coordinates we may assume that the singularity is at the origin $(0,0)$, and that the equation of the curve is
$$y^2 - e x^2 + a y^3 + b x y^2  + c  x^2 y +  d x^3=0$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d \in \mathbb{R}$, not all $0$, $e\in \mathbb{R}$.  (Assume also that the cubic is irreducible).

The curve has a rational [parametrization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%20y%5E2%20-%20e%20x%5E2%20%2B%20a%20y%5E3%20%2B%20b%20x%20y%5E2%20%2B%20c%20x%5E2%20y%20%2B%20d%20x%5E3%3D%3D0%20%26%26%20y%20%3D%3D%20t%20x%2C%20%7Bx%2Cy%7D%5D)
$$r(t) =(x(t), y(t)) = \left(\frac{e-t^2}{ a t^3 + b t^2 + c t + d}, \frac{et-t^3}{a t^3 + b t^2 + c t + d}\right)$$

The inflection points of the curve occur at the points for which $r'(t) \parallel r''(t)$. Now, the determinant of the matrix $(r'(t), r''(t))$ [equals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det%5B%7BD%5B%7B%28e-t%5E2%29%2F%28%20a%20t%5E3%20%2B%20b%20t%5E2%20%2B%20c%20t%20%2B%20d%29%2C%20%28e%20t%20-%20t%5E3%29%2F%28a%20t%5E3%20%2B%20b%20t%5E2%20%2B%20c%20t%20%2B%20d%29%7D%2C%20%7Bt%2C1%7D%5D%2CD%5B%7B%28e-t%5E2%29%2F%28%20a%20t%5E3%20%2B%20b%20t%5E2%20%2B%20c%20t%20%2B%20d%29%2C%20%28e%20t%20-%20t%5E3%29%2F%28a%20t%5E3%20%2B%20b%20t%5E2%20%2B%20c%20t%20%2B%20d%29%7D%2C%20%7Bt%2C2%7D%5D%7D%5D)
$$\frac {2( (a e +c) t^3 + 3 (b e+d) t^2 + 3 e(a e +c) t + e(b e+d))}{(a t^3 + b t^2 + c t + d)^3}$$

However, the discriminant of a cubic $p t^3 + 3 q t^2 + 3 e p t + e q$ [equals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5B%20p%20t%5E3%20%2B%203%20q%20t%5E2%20%20%2B%203%20e%20p%20t%20%2B%20e%20q%2C%20t%5D)
$$-108e(e p^2-q^2)^2$$

Conclusion:

If  a real cubic curve has a real node singularity ($e>0$) then it cannot have three real inflection points.

Is there an algebraic geometric reason behind it? I cannot see it right now. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: You may be able to leverage [Klein's formula](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/personer/vit/ragnip/raggm04.pdf). See [this book](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonalgebr0000cool/page/118/mode/2up) pp 108-118.

Comment: @Jan-Magnus Økland: Thank you, that is useful information, I will take a look at Coollidge's book and that paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflection points are 3-torsion points for the chord and tangent group law on the nonsingular points of a plane cubic. But the chord-and-tangent group law on the smooth real points of a real nodal plane cubic is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^\times$, which has only the identity as a 3-torsion point.

Comment: That's very interesting, I will have to look up the group law, saw it somewhere in an Elliptic Curves book.